# Is it possible to have an anonymous method when creating a list of items, with .NET + Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, anonymous-methods

i'm trying to do the following, but not sure how ...

```
var foo = new Foo
    {
        Id = MyRandom<int>(1, 100),
        Name = MyRandom<string>(5,20),
        MyPets = MyRandom<bool>() ?
            new IList<Pet>
            (petList =>
                { 
                   var x = MyRandom<int>(1, 4);
                   for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                   {
                       petList.Add(new Pet(MyRandom<string>(1,15));
                   }
                }
            : null
    };
```

so .. this creates a random list of pets.

Any ideas?

Comment: yeah, it was just pseduo code... to get the point across..

Comment: i thought that but i noticed it and it annoyed me... sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Instead, you can create a lambda expression, then call it immediately:

```
MyRandom<bool>() ? null : (new Func<IList<Pet>>(() => { return ... })()
```

Comment: @SLaks - how do i return a new list with the items randomly added, though?

Comment: @Slaks - yeah :) that's what i tried .. but what do i need to do to ADD an item to petlist? ie. what is the petlist variable?

Comment: @Pure: You need to declare the variable in the lambda.

Comment: hmmm. i'm just not getting it :( Here's my latest attempt: http://codepaste.net/dcux6p

Comment: @Pure: You need to call the delegate by adding `()` at the end.

Comment: AHH! so close :) Thanks heaps mate. I really do appreciate it. Totally missed that last bit....

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
var foo = new Foo
    {
        Id = MyRandom<int>(1, 100),
        Name = MyRandom<string>(5,20),
        MyPets = MyRandom<bool>() ?
            Enumerable.Range(0, MyRandom<int>(1, 4))
                .Select(_ => new Pet(MyRandom<string>(1,15)))
                .ToList()
            : null
    };
```